# Group cells in a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, cell

I have a DataTable, holding Decimal values in all cells.
In that table, I need to have 3 value groups with identical values in each group's cells that are spread over the table.

With 3 NumUpDown controls, I wish to control the values in each one of the groups cells in the table.

I can easily access and control the value of each cell in the table (`MyTable.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex] = numUpDown.Value`), but I did not find any way to define the groups and distinguish them from each other.

ASAIK, table cells have no properties that can be used to distinguish them from each other.
One option may be the building of another, identical indexing table that will hold the grouping information, but I am looking for something more straight forward.

(There may be a workaround using the actual initial identical values in the group, but this is far from being safe).
Any idea will be highly appreciated!
thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. How are these rows related to each other? Do you have a foreign key column in the table which is used to identify the groups?

Comment: I can not refer to rows but only to individual cells. Each row or column may hold cells from any of the 3 groups.
I have no index column because such column can not point to a cell (unless using a complex numbering algo), but your comment made me think of adding an index column for each table column, rather than building an extra indexing table.
I any case, I am still hoping someone will come with a simple magic brilliant idea.

Comment: I assume that the table is filled from the database. It would be a good start to show us the table and the types of the columns. You should also show us the code where you load it.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The table is 3 cols by 26 rows of Decimal type.
The table is initially built as an empty table and displayed by a bind datagridview.
The datagridview individual cells are then selected by the user in groups that are manually filled with values from 3 different NumUpdown controls, and automatically writes the values back into the table.
Upon program closure, the table is saved as user settings (settings.user, HTML). 
When the data is written from the datagird to the datatable, it can not preserve the grouping from the datagrid. (DataTables do not have cell formatting properties).

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested, I solved this by adding extra columns to the table.
For each cell, there is added cell with the color (or other) information.
When the datagrid opens, it reads the added cells and decides on the basic cells color by the information in the extra cells. 
Here is the full working code of a test program I designed:
(To run, build a WinForm with a DataGridView 'fareGrid' and 3 NumUpDown controls) 
(I still have a problem with the colors that do not work (see comments in the code), but I'll post it as a separate question).
This is a small part of a program that calculates variable electrical energy cost per used time (day-of-week, hour, season)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//This is a test program to do the following:
//1. Build an empty data table of 26 rows by 6 columns.
//2. The Table is the DataSource to a DataGridView.
//3. The DataGrid Colomns 0-3 can be filled with decimals by one of 3 NumericUpDown      controls.
//3. For each cell in cols 0-2 there is one in cols 3-5 that holds info which NumUpDn  was used.
//4. Each NumUpDn has specific color. The corresponding cells have the same backcolor.
//5. When the program starts, it builds the table from the Settings, and displays the  table in the datagrid.
//6. The cells in cols 0-2 are supposed to get the colors ad indicated in cols 3-5, but they do not.  


namespace DataGridViewTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable fareTable = new DataTable();

    int rowIndex;
    int colIndex;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buildFareTable("fareTable");
        // Load the table (if exists)
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.fareTable != null)
            fareTable = Properties.Settings.Default.fareTable;
        paintFareTableCells(fareTable);

    }

    //Build the initial data table of 26R X 6C
    //Columns 3-5 are used to hold the color information of cols 0-2
    public void buildFareTable(string fareTableName)
    {
        fareTable.TableName = fareTableName;
        fareTable.Columns.Add("Weekday", typeof(Decimal));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("HalfDay", typeof(Decimal));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("Weekend", typeof(Decimal));

        //Adding 3 indexing columns that will hold the tables cell group
        fareTable.Columns.Add("IWeekday", typeof(String));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("IHalfDay", typeof(String));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("Iweekend", typeof(String));

        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 26; rowIndex++)
        {
            fareTable.Rows.Add();
        }
    }

    public void paintFareTableCells(DataTable fareTable)
    {
        fareDataGrid.DataSource = fareTable;

        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 26; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < 3; colIndex++)
            {
                switch (fareTable.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex + 3].ToString())   //Check the color index columns 3-5
                {
                    case "low": fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;  
                        break;
                    case "med": fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow; 
                        break;
                    case "high": fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;  
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                // Diagnostics: Check cell's color. At this point, Colors are OK!  
                Color color = fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor;  
            }
        }
    }

   //Update the cells by 3 NumUpDn controls.
    private void numericUpDownFareHigh_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editFareTableCells(sender);
    }
    private void numericUpDownFareMed_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editFareTableCells(sender);
    }

    private void numericUpDownFareLow_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editFareTableCells(sender);
    }

    public void editFareTableCells(Object sender)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in fareDataGrid.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex < 3)
            {
                cell.Value = ((NumericUpDown)sender).Value;
                cell.Style.BackColor = ((NumericUpDown)sender).BackColor;
                fareDataGrid[cell.ColumnIndex + 3, cell.RowIndex].Value = ((NumericUpDown)sender).Tag;   //Uses cols 3-5 to hold cost level info.
            }
        }
    }

    //Use settings to preserve the data
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.fareTable = this.fareTable;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
  }
}
```